# How to find min() value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have in my DB a column of varchar type.

Table name: Transcations

Column name :authprocess

I want to find min() value on the varchar column.

```
authprocess  

A1D1

A1D3

A1D4

A1D1

A1B1

A1D5  
......
```

i am using the command
select min(authprocess) from Trnascation
then it give the "0000" value

Please tell me the command in Mysql.

Comment: What are you expecting MIN() to return? The element with the smallest length? Normally, min only works with number (int, decimal, etc) column types

Comment: smallest string, lexographic order is my guess... I'd be surprised if that's not how MIN behaves.

Comment: Are those numbers in hex? Maybe you want to convert it to a decimal number first (`CONV(authprocess, 16, 10)`)?

Answer (score 0):

MIN() makes no real sense for a character string, your best bet is to do a string sort by ascending values and select the top one perhaps??

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM table ORDER ASC;
```

Comment: sure it does. if it has an order, it has a min.

Comment: Top one can be selected with `LIMIT 1`

Comment: hey fileoffset please write the proper query   table name: Transcation and column name:authprocess  SELECT TOP 1 FROM........please complete the query

Answer (score 0):

`MIN()` takes the first entry after sorting. For text columns, the sorting order is ascii order, so for alpha-numeric data it's `0..9a..zA..Z`

You must have an entry with the value `0000`, which will of course be the minimum.

It sounds like you need to restrict your search to "valid" entries. Assuming entries are valid if they have form letter-digit-letter-digit, try this:

```
select min(authprocess)
from Transcations
where authprocess regexp '[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d'
```

You can adjust the regex to suit whatever your needs are - eg perhaps it's `A-digit-D-digit`, which would match the regex `'A\dD\d'`